# SBT Compiler Plugin as Transitive Dependency

Tags: scala, macros, sbt

I have a library that uses the macro paradise plugin (referred to as macro-provider library). In the `build.sbt`,

```
addCompilerPlugin("org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % "2.0.0" cross CrossVersion.full)
```

to gain access to the **macro annotations**.

When adding the macro library as a `libraryDependency` to a separate project (referred to as macro-consumer project), the annotations are present, but the macro implementation is never called. Adding the macro paradise compiler plugin to the macro-consumer project `libraryDependencies` solves the problem.

*Is it possible to include compiler plugins as transitive dependencies? This would free consumers of the macro library from adding the required plugin.*

---

**Update #1:**

*The `addCompilerPlugin` helper adds the dependency to the `libraryDependencies` and sets the dependency with a `configuration = Some("plugin->default(compile)")` within the macro-provider library.*

*Adding the `paradise` dependency in the `libraryDependencies` of the macro-provider library causes the  artifact to show up in the macro-consumer project. It does not add the dependency as a compiler plugin.*

**Update #2:**

*Setting `autoCompilerPlugins := true` in the macro-consumer project in conjunction with **Update #1** does not resolve the issue.*

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found to resolve this issue was by adding a `sbt-plugin` sub-module that includes the settings required. The plugin is very basic,

```
package fixme

import sbt._
import Keys._

object Plugin extends sbt.Plugin {
  val paradiseVersion = "2.0.0"
  val fixmeVersion = "1.4"
  val fixmeSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] = Seq(
    resolvers += "tysonjh releases" at "http://tysonjh.github.io/releases/",
    libraryDependencies <++= (scalaVersion) { v: String ⇒
      (if (v.startsWith("2.10")) List("org.scalamacros" %% "quasiquotes" % paradiseVersion % "compile")
      else Nil) :+
        "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % v % "compile" :+
        "com.tysonjh" %% "fixme" % fixmeVersion % "compile"
    },
    addCompilerPlugin("org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % paradiseVersion cross CrossVersion.full))
}
```

This can be used by including in your `project/plugins.sbt`,

```
resolvers += "tysonjh releases" at "http://tysonjh.github.io/releases/"

addSbtPlugin("com.tysonjh" % "sbt-fixme" % "1.4")
```

and the `build.sbt` file,

```
fixmeSettings
```

The sbt-plugin settings add the macro paradise plugin as a compiler dependency and the macro implementation as a library dependency.